# Cannot remove a uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an iPad app and i utilise a UISplitview for my program.
Now on the main detail view of my program i have a uiscrollview on which i add two labels.

```
  UIScrollView *scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 1600);
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

This is the code i create on the first main page. Now imagine we push the second view, from that second view i can access everything by saying

```
 [self.detailViewController.view addSubview:detailViewController.Image];
```

but when i try to add labels to the subview saying

```
[self.detailViewController.view.scoll...
```

but i cannot find the scroll object, BUT the background of the scroll set in the first view comes over in the second view. AND i cannot change the background of the first view.

I decided to make a second scrollview untop of the first (which works) but i much rather know how i can access the first view i created throughout the whole program since it would negate me having to waste space creating scroll views. but if i have to create all the views i need i want to be able to somehow delete or release them so the picture from scrollview one doesn't get transferred all the way too scrollview 3

Thank You

Comment: scroll is a local variable in the code you show. If you need to access it from outside that method, you should make it a property of your detailViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create properties for all the variables that you want to access from other classes . So in your case

**DetailsViewController.h**

```
@interface DetailsViewController : UIViewController {

  // class member variables here that can be accessed
  // anywhere in your class (only in your class)
}

@property(nonatomic, strong)
    //retain instead of strong if you are not using ARC or other types (weak, copy, readonly)
     SomeClassThatYouHave *propertyThatCanBeAccessed
//declare here public instance methods
@end
```

In your **DetailsViewController.m** you will have:

```
@interface DetailsViewController (Private)
//declare private methods here or private properties
@end

@implementation DetailsViewController
@synthesize propertyThatCanBeAccessed;

//methods implementation here
@end
```

Now you can access the property of your `DetailsViewController` like `detailsViewControllerInstance.propertyThatCanBeAccessed` but you must alloc/init the instance.

Hope that this will give you an idea of class structure in the future.